# compare element in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to compare each element of array real with each element of array number. And if there is any matches push them in array add so I can see them. In this case add must be 2,3,6,10,14 if code is good.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
        <script>
        var real=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,14,16,233,235,245,2,5,7,236,237];
        var number=[2,3,6,10,12,13,14,172,122,234];
        var add=[];
        for (k=0; k<number.length; k++)
                { 
                    for (w=0; w<real.length; w++)
                        { 
                            if (number[k]==real[w]); 
                                {
                                    add.push(number[k],real[w]);
                                }
                        };

                };
        document.write(add+"<br>");
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more elegant and readable solution:

```
var matched = [];
real.forEach(function(realNum) {
    number.forEach(function(numberNum) {
        if(realNum == numberNum && matched.indexOf(realNum) === -1) {
            matched.push(realNum);   
        }                     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short and simple solution using `Array.forEach` and `Array.indexOf` functions:

```
var real = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,14,16,233,235,245,2,5,7,236,237],
    number = [2,3,6,10,12,13,14,172,122,234],
    add = [];

real.forEach(function(v) {
    if (number.indexOf(v) !== -1 && this.indexOf(v) === -1) this.push(v);
}, add);

console.log(add);   // [2, 3, 6, 10, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it using ES6:

```js
var real = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 14, 16, 233, 235, 245, 2, 5, 7, 236, 237];
var number = [2, 3, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 172, 122, 234];

var filtered = real.filter(x => number.indexOf(x) > -1);
var unique = new Set(filtered);

document.body.innerHTML = [...unique];
```

Answer (score 0):

*try this way...*
Sorted the main [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), removed duplicates and the find the common elements from both the arrays.

```
var main = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,14,16,233,235,245,2,5,7,236,237];
var compare = [2,3,6,10,12,13,14,172,122,234];

function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
console.log('Sorted Array :', main.sort(compareNumbers) );
// Sorted Array : [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 10, 14, 16, 233, 235, 236, 237, 245]

Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var unique = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var current = this[i];
        if (unique.indexOf(current) < 0) unique.push(current);
    }
    return unique;
}    
console.log('Unique Array Elements:', main.unique() );
// Unique Array Elements: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 14, 16, 233, 235, 236, 237, 245]

function commonElements(arr1, arr2) {
    var common = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j] ) {
                common.push( arr1[i] );
                j == arr2.length; // To break the loop;
            }
        }
    }
    return common;
}

console.log('Common Elements from Both Arrays : ', commonElements(main.unique(), compare.unique()) );
//Common Elements from Both Arrays :  [2, 3, 6, 10, 14]
```